# Openpyxl cell value not coming

Tags: python, openpyxl

I come from Matlab environment, and recently, trying to dive into python. Reading from excel is one of the more important day to day thing which Matlab accomplishes by creating a COM excel component, deriving workbook and then sheet and then range from it. Was glad to see similar approach from workbook to sheet to cell/range.

So,

```
w = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:/ass.csv')
s = w.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
c = s.cell('a2')
```

and finally: `c.value` should give me the value, and `c.value = 12` should assign the value. Both don’t seem to happen. However, once I assign `c.value = 12`, then further calling of c.value gives me 12, though no change has happened in the underlying csv.

When I try stuff like `s.get_highest_column()` I get the right expected answer. `w.get_sheet_names()` also gives the expected response. Any suggestions as to what could have gone wrong.

Comment: did you save the sheet? That's a key step. If you don't explicitly save the workbook, the change won't be reflected in the underlying file.

Comment: 1) accessing data in sheet was not working 2) i did w.save(), but still no effect. as is said, w and s objects did behave alright in properties i checked like w.getsheetnames, s.gethighestcolumn, but cell.value does not work. in fact, i wonder if any of cell object properties or method was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openpyxl` only works on Excel 2007 and later formats, the files normally having an extension `.xlsx` or `.xlsm`.

If you want to read the old `.csv` format use the [CVS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

AFAIK there is no Python library that will open both the `.csv` and the more modern `.xls` resp. `.xlsx` files. If you want to have that flexibility you can interface with Excel using COM from Python as well. I mostly use `win32com.client` for that, but you can probably use `comtypes.client` as well.